# How to create an app that can self uninstall after a time

Tags: android

I've created an app for demo and want to give it to several users, but it is about a service that is not yet copyrighted.

Since it's a demo app, I would like to know if there's a way to make the app self-delete after a given time (like 3 days after installation for example) ?
Or maybe a way to alter data so it would become not usable ?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not working like that without user interaction if a device is not rooted.

I think it would be big security issue to let app uninstall other apps or itself.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

But if you want to alter data i would simply use for example a timer and prompt the user to buy the pro version.

The data you can unvalid with a token or sth else.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(data_security)